# Javascript: Find all unescaped dollar signs ($) in template literal

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a message template in a string, and I'm trying to preview a sample message for the user.  In the preview, I want to highlight unescaped dollar signs `$` that are not part of an approved mail merge token.

### Sample Message Template

```
<h1>Title</h1>

Good Dollar --> A new card costs (\$13.00)<br/>
Bad Dollar --> A new card costs ($13.00)<br/>
Good Dollar --> A new card costs \$13.00<br/>
Bad Dollar --> A new card costs $13.00<br/>
badDollar$ goodDollar\$
<br/>
Email Address: ${msg.from}<br/>
Reply-To Address: ${msg.replyTo}<br/>
Email Address: ${msg.address}<br/>
```

### Desired Preview Result

[image]

I got it working with the following code, but it feels really clunky.  There has to be a better way than this.

```
    preview(string) {
        let msg = {
            from: 'noreply@company.com',
            replyTo: 'reply@company.com',
            address: 'customer@gmail.com'
        }

        this.user.organization.customFields.forEach((cf) => msg[`cf_${cf.name}`] = this.user.customFields[cf.name].value)

        let slashDollar = 'SLASHDOLLAR';
        string = string.replace(new RegExp(/\\\$/, "g"), slashDollar)
        string = eval('`' + string + '`')
        let pattern = new RegExp(/\$/, "g")
        if (pattern.test(string)) {
            this.MessageService.alert('You need to prefix every dollar sign "$" with a backslash "\\" unless the dollar sign is part of a mail merge token', true)
            string = string.replace(pattern, (match) => `<span style="color:#ef2160">${match}</span>`)
        }
        string = string.replace(new RegExp(slashDollar, "g"), '$')
        return string
    }
```

After calling `eval`, any remaining `$` that is not escaped needs to be indicated as an error.  I would like to just use a single `replace` (instead of replacing 3 times), but I couldn't seem to match `$` without a preceding `\`.  I tried quite a few variations of the following, but with no luck.  So is there anyway to do this without replacing every `\$` with an intermediate token then replacing every `$` then replacing the intermediate tokens with `$`?

```
string = string.replace(new RegExp(/[^\\]\$/, "g"), (match) => `${match[0]}<span style="color:#ef2160">${match[1]}</span>`)
```

Comment: ... make use of a [negative lookbehind](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookbehind) like with this example [`(?<!\\)\$`](https://regex101.com/r/ZY7fz5/1)

Comment: Why not use a well established JavaScript templating engine like [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) or [Handlebars JS](https://handlebarsjs.com/)?

Comment: @3limin4t0r that's great point, and the answer is complicated, but at present that's not an option.

Comment: @PeterSeliger thanks. That's just what I needed to get me pointed in the right direction. I'll post my solution in a moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @PeterSeliger for his comment about using a negative look behind.  The problem was a little more complicated than that, but that was the missing piece that I needed.

My main problem is that the calling `eval(...)` stripped the `\` from each `\$`, so after calling `eval(...)` , there was no way to differentiate which `$` were originally escaped.

However, I was able to combine a negative lookbehind with a negative lookahead to find each `$` that was not preceded by a `\` and was not followed by a `{`.  This allowed me to identify the erroneous dollar signs **before** calling `eval`.

### Final Solution:

```
    preview(string) {
        let msg = {
            from: 'noreply@company.com',
            replyTo: 'reply@company.com',
            address: 'customer@gmail.com'
        }

        let erroneousDollarSigns = new RegExp("(?<!\\\\)\\$(?!{)", "g");
        if (erroneousDollarSigns.test(string)) {
            this.MessageService.alert('You need to prefix every dollar sign "$" with a backslash "\\" unless the dollar sign is part of a mail merge token', true)
            string = string.replace(erroneousDollarSigns, (match) => `<span style="color:#ef2160">${match}</span>`)
        }

        return eval('`' + string + '`')
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

... make use of a [*negative lookbehind*](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind#lookbehind) like with this example regex ... [`(?<!\\)\$`](https://regex101.com/r/ZY7fz5/1).

And of cause, within a (template) string, the dollar-escaping backslash has to be escaped too. The provided regex does fail for a single backslash within the string.

```js
const msg = {
  from: 'noreply@company.com',
  replyTo: 'reply@company.com',
  address: 'customer@gmail.com'
}
const htmlTemplate = `<h1>Title</h1>

Good Dollar --> A new card costs (\\$13.00)<br/>
Bad Dollar --> A new card costs ($13.00)<br/>
Good Dollar --> A new card costs \\$13.00<br/>
Bad Dollar --> A new card costs \$13.00<br/>
badDollar\$ goodDollar\\$

<br/>
<br/>

Email Address: ${msg.from}<br/>
Reply-To Address: ${msg.replyTo}<br/>
Email Address: ${msg.address}<br/>`;


const regXUnescapedDollar = (/(?<!\\)\$/g);

document.body.innerHTML = htmlTemplate
  .replace(regXUnescapedDollar, '<span style="color:#ef2160">$</span>')
  .replace(/\\/g, ''); // replace backslash within text content output.
```

Comment: This was super helpful.  However, it won't work for me because I can't escape the backslashes, i.e. `\$13.00` can't be `\\$13.00` because I'm passing the string to a backend templating engine.